# How to fit one div into another div of a modal

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a react app and I have a modal which props is a child. This child is gonna be rendered inside the modal as the modal body. My problem is that the modal body doesn't fit the modal. I've been changing the CSS during hours but I can't find the solution to fix my problem. This is my code:

This is the modal component (the important thing is the body of the modal you don't have to understand everything):

```
import { Fragment } from "react"

interface Props {
  title: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  isForm?: boolean;
  closeModal: () => void;
  acceptModal?: () => void;
}

const Modal: React.FC<Props> = ({title, children, isForm=false, closeModal, acceptModal}) => {
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <div className="modal_container">
          <div className="modal_content">

            <div className="modal_header">
              <h4>{title}</h4>
              <button role="header_close_modal" 
                  onClick={closeModal}>
                X
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal_body">
              {children}
            </div>

            <div className="modal_footer">
              <input className="modal_accept" 
                  type={isForm ? "submit" : "button"}
                  role="accept_modal"
                  onClick={isForm ? null : acceptModal}
                  value="Accept" />
              <button className="modal_cancel" 
                  role="footer_close_modal"
                  onClick={closeModal}>
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <style jsx>
        {`
          .modal_container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: rgb(216 216 216 / 0.6);
            z-index: 10;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          }
          .modal_content{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            min-width: 40vw;
            height: 30vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px grey;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
          .modal_header{
            height: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
          }
          .modal_header button,
          .modal_header input[type="button"],
          .modal_header input[type="submit"]{
            border: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: 600;        
          }
          .modal_body{
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: inline-block;
          }
          .modal_footer{
            display: flex;
            height: 30px;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            padding: 0 10px;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .modal_footer button,
          .modal_footer input[type="button"],
          .modal_footer input[type="submit"]{
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            padding: 0 15px;
            height: 25px;
          }
          .modal_footer input[type="submit"].modal_accept,
          .modal_footer input[type="button"].modal_accept{
            background-color: #239623;
            color: #fff;
            margin-right: 5px;
          }
          modal_footer input[type="submit"].modal_accept:hover,
          modal_footer input[type="button"].modal_accept:hover{
            background-color: #1e7c1e;
          }
          .modal_footer .modal_cancel{
            background-color: #868686;
            color: #fff;
          }
          .modal_footer .modal_cancel:hover{
            background-color: #757575;
          }
          .modal_footer button:focus,
          .modal_footer input[type="button"]:focus,
          .modal_footer input[type="submit"]:focus{
            outline: none;
          }
        `}
        </style>
      </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Modal
```

This is the parent component which calls the modal:

```
{ showModal && (
            <Modal title={rule.title} closeModal={() => {setShowModal(false)}}>
                <div className="wrap">
                    <h1>Description</h1>
                    <div className="card">
                        <p>{rule.description}</p>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Mitigation</h1>
                    <div className="card">
                        <p>{rule.mitigation}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Modal>)}
```

And the CSS of the parent component:

```
.card {
                background: #fff;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                padding: 3px 10px;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-bottom: 6px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between; 
            }

            .wrap {
                background: #e8e8e8;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 5px;
                max-width: 1000px;
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            
            h1 {
                font-size: 1.5em;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: .5em;
            }
            
            p {
                margin-bottom: 2em;
                color: #666;
            }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fit the body in the modal? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card {
    background: #fff;
    box - shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 3px 10px;
    font - size: 12px;
    margin - bottom: 6px;
    border - radius: 3px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: can you try like this

Comment: You may want to remove the spaces and also explain the code.

Comment: maybe the problem is in the modal CSS

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove min-width and height from the modal_content like this:

```
.modal_content{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px grey;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
```

[image]
Thank you!